# EV3 PID line follower with medium motors

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

I am stuck on creating an efficient line follower with medium motors.

The problem is that the motors are rotating in different ways so I can't use the steering block.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

From a programming perspective I can't help you since I haven't programmed anything since the Mindstorms NXT.  The simplest solution I can think of, without seeing your set-up, is to offset one of the motors and add a 1:1 gear drive using 16 tooth gears that would simply reverse the motor output on that side.
[image]